# Same SDE with different initial conditions

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I think my statement is wrong, but cannot find exactly in which point I am confused.
Please forgive my sloppy notations.

There is a SDE : $ dX_{t}=\mu(X_{t})dt+\sigma(X_{t})dW_{t}$

where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are both uniformly Lipschitz continuous and an initial condition $x_{0}$

Then according to Ito’s uniqueness/existence theorem, there is a unique strong solution to the SDE given by:

$X_{t}=x_{0}+ \int_{0}^{t}\mu(X_{s})ds+\int_{0}^{t}\sigma(X_{s})ds$ almost surely.

Suppose I consider two stochastic processes following the same SDE and filtration with only difference in their initial condition. Then according to the theorem, is the following statement true?

For any given $t>0$,

$X_{A,t}-X_{B,t}=x_{A,0}+ \int_{0}^{t}\mu(X_{s})ds+\int_{0}^{t}\sigma(X_{s})ds-(x_{B,0}+ \int_{0}^{t}\mu(X_{s})ds+\int_{0}^{t}\sigma(X_{s})ds)$
$X_{A,t}-X_{B,t} =x_{A,0}-x_{b,0}$ almost surely.

I think this must be wrong, as this statement can be easily rejected in a simple ODE.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is false because you actually have dependence on the initial condition on the RHS too

$$X_{t}-Y_{t}=x_{0}+ \int_{0}^{t}\mu(X_{s}^{x_{0}})ds+\int_{0}^{t}\sigma(X_{s}^{x_{0}})ds-(y_{0}+ \int_{0}^{t}\mu(Y_{s}^{y_{0}})ds+\int_{0}^{t}\sigma(Y_{s}^{y_{0}})ds).$$

For example, for geometric Brownian motion we have

$$X_{t}=X_{0}e^{(\mu-\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2})t+B_{t}}$$

and

$$Y_{t}=Y_{0}e^{(\mu-\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2})t+B_{t}}$$

and so their difference is not a constant.

However, for smooth-enough coefficients there is smooth dependence on the initial conditions.

Kunita's lectures cover this eg. [Lectures on
Stochastic Flows And Applications](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/%7Epubl/ln/tifr78.pdf), i.e. depending on the regularity of the coefficients we have analogous differentiability in initial conditions

[image]

Another source is in Varadhan's notes too [Stochastic1](https://math.nyu.edu/%7Evaradhan/fall06/Stochastic1.pdf)

[image]

The proof goes through creating new systems satisfied by the derivative processes and then showing existence-uniqueness for the entire system.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Now I completely get it!